# iCloud: Getting the already existing public URL for a file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icloud

my OS X Lion app allows the user to make iCloud files available for public. I use `URLForPublishingUbiquitousItemAtURL` for that.

I can present that URL to the user after calling that method. But is there also a way to get the same URL after a file has been published (and not changed)? For example if the user wants to see that URL on another device?

Yes I could call `URLForPublishingUbiquitousItemAtURL` again, but how do I know if the file has already been published or not?

My first idea was to create some kind of Key-Value Data into the iCloud that contains that URL for all files (that have an public url). But I can't believe that there is none easier way...

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to retrieve, or create, the public URL for a file in iCloud.

If that is the case, then use URLForPublishingUbiquitousItemAtURL:expirationDate:error:

It returns a URL which can be emailed to users to download the files.

```
- (NSURL *)URLForPublishingUbiquitousItemAtURL:(NSURL *)url expirationDate:(NSDate
**)outDate error:(NSError **)error
```

**Parameters:**

- url - Specify the URL of the item in the cloud that you want to
  share. The URL must be prefixed with the base URL returned from the
  URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: (page 61) method that corresponds
  to the item’s location.
- outDate - On input, a pointer to a variable for a date object. On
  output, this parameter contains the date after which the item is no
  longer available at the returned URL. You may specify nil for this
  parameter if you are not interested in the date
- error - On input, a pointer to variable for an NSError object. If an
  error occurs, this pointer is set to an NSError object containing
  information about the error. You may specify nil for this parameter
  if you do not want the error information.

**Return Value**

A URL with which users can download a copy of the item at url. Returns nil if the URL could not be created for any reason.

**Discussion**

This method creates a snapshot of the specified file and places that copy in a temporary iCloud location where
it can be accessed by other users using the returned URL. The snapshot reflects the contents of the file at the
time the URL was generated and is not updated when subsequent changes are made to the original file in the
user’s iCloud storage. The snapshot file remains available at the specified URL until the date specified in the
outDate parameter, after which it is automatically deleted.
Your application must have access to the network for this call to succeed.

So, if as you say, you need to check if it was successfully published, check the error.

Source: [NSFileManagerClass @ Developer.Apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/NSFileManager_Class.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, but I know all that. The question is how do I get the URL of an file, that has already been published and did not change since then...